# configureWebpack function mode How to configure unplugin-vue-components plugin？

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

````
```
````

const Components = require('unplugin-vue-components/webpack')
const { ElementPlusResolver } = require('unplugin-vue-components/resolvers')

```
configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      Components({
        resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()]
      })
    ]
},
============================================================================

How to change the above plugin to the following way?

configureWebpack: (config) => {
//How to do it here
}
```